# Select everything except rows with maxvalue in certain column

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a table with data and I'm trying to select some values with lower value than maximum. I am using IBExpert, I need to do this in SQL because I am working on a Firebird database. My table looks like this:

```
UID      TYP  ID_RODZICA  ID_DZIALKI  PRZED_PO  GRUPA  DTW               OSOW  DTU  OSOU
 17 170  K         5 765       3 551  0             1                                     
163 759  N         5 765      53 084  0             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 760  N         5 765      49 796  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 761  N         5 765      49 426  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 762  N         5 765      53 085  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 763  N         5 765      53 086  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 764  N         5 765      53 087  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 765  N         5 765      53 088  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 766  N         5 765       8 940  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 767  N         5 765      41 931  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
253 171  N         5 765      41 931  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 172  N         5 765      53 088  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 173  N         5 765       8 940  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 174  N         5 765      49 796  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 175  N         5 765      49 426  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 176  N         5 765      53 085  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 177  N         5 765      53 086  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 178  N         5 765      67 386  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 179  N         5 765      67 387  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 180  N         5 765      67 388  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21
```

What I want is to select only rows with GRUPA values lower than maximum, here max value is 3, but sometimes it might be 5, 7, 11 or whatever, so I can't specify the value.

It should look like this:

```
UID      TYP  ID_RODZICA  ID_DZIALKI  PRZED_PO  GRUPA  DTW               OSOW  DTU  OSOU
 17 170  K         5 765       3 551  0             1                                     
163 759  N         5 765      53 084  0             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 760  N         5 765      49 796  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 761  N         5 765      49 426  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 762  N         5 765      53 085  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 763  N         5 765      53 086  1             1  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 764  N         5 765      53 087  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 765  N         5 765      53 088  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 766  N         5 765       8 940  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21             
163 767  N         5 765      41 931  0             2  29.03.2018 11:45    21
```

I've tried with:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM (select * FROM obdg where ID_RODZICA = '5765') c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT c2.*
    FROM (select * from obdg WHERE ID_RODZICA = '5765') c2
WHERE c1.GRUPA = MAXVALUE(c2.GRUPA))
```

eliminating the max value, but result of that is simply nothing. When I use < instead of = before MAXVALUE(c2.GRUPA) I get:

```
UID      TYP  ID_RODZICA  ID_DZIALKI  PRZED_PO  GRUPA  DTW               OSOW  DTU  OSOU
253 171  N         5 765      41 931  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 172  N         5 765      53 088  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 173  N         5 765       8 940  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 174  N         5 765      49 796  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 175  N         5 765      49 426  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 176  N         5 765      53 085  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 177  N         5 765      53 086  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 178  N         5 765      67 386  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 179  N         5 765      67 387  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21             
253 180  N         5 765      67 388  0             3  29.03.2018 21:14    21
```

obviously, as I am eliminating all values lower than max (as far as I understand that).

I also tried something much simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM OBDG
WHERE ID_RODZICA = '5765' AND GRUPA < MAXVALUE(GRUPA)
```

but again I get nothing in results window. If I change "MAXVALUE(GRUPA)" to just "3" I get expected results, but again, I can't specify the max value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function [`MAXVALUE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-maxvalue) does not do what you think it does: it selects the highest value from the list of values, you only pass a single value. In your example code, the condition `c1.GRUPA = MAXVALUE(c2.GRUPA)` is the same as just doing `c1.GRUPA = c2.GRUPA`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, do you have any suggestion on how to do it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your question, you want:

```
select a.* 
from OBDG a 
where a.ID_RODZICA = '5765' 
and a.GRUPA <> (select max(GRUPA) 
                from OBDG b 
                where b.ID_RODZICA = a.ID_RODZICA)
```

That is: select all rows where `GRUPA` is not equal to the maximum value of `GRUPA` (for that `ID_RODZICA`).

As to why your queries don't work:

In your first query, the subquery in the `NOT EXISTS` will always produce rows given the example data, and in a `NOT EXISTS`  this means the result is always false, and therefor the query as whole produces no rows.

The second query you tried doesn't work, because [`MAXVALUE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-maxvalue) does not do what you think it does. It is not an aggregate function, but instead from the list of values passed as parameters, it will return the highest value. Given you pass a single value, it will return that value. Which results in `GRUPA < MAXVALUE(GRUPA)` being equivalent to `GRUPA < GRUPA` which is never true, so again it produces no rows.

Comment: Well, Dear Sir, you just made my day. I was searching, trying and failing for the solution for almost 5 hours. This here is what I was looking for. thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaciejCzapiewski Good to hear. If my answer helped you, then please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't accept your answer as solution to this question because I don't have 15+ point in reputation. I will click it again as soon as I get 15 points!

Comment: @MaciejCzapiewski I think you are trying to upvote instead of accepting the answer. As far as I know there is no reputation limit for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Lower" than the maximum means that no higher value exists.  So . . .

```
SELECT o.*
FROM obdg o
WHERE ID_RODZICA = 5765 AND - I'm guessing it is a number so the single quotes are not necessary
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM obdg o2
                  WHERE ID_RODZICA = 5765 AND o2.GRUPA > o.GRUPA
                  );
```

There are definitely other ways of expressing this query.  This seems closest to what you were trying.

Note that I removed the single quotes around `5765`.  Ids are usually numbers.  If yours is really a string, then use the single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. Unfortunately using your solution I get all rows with value "3" in GRUPA column, and what I want are rows with values "1" and "2" (lower than maximum value). Same if there would be values from 1 to 5 in a column I want all rows with values 1-4.